# javascript open parent window from NewForm.aspx

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript in the NewForm.aspx. It works but opens the link in the NewForm.apsx. I need to open the link in the parent window where NewForm.aspx was initiated from. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect()
{
  var inputcCtrls = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(m=0; m<inputcCtrls.length; m++)
   {
       if(inputcCtrls[m].type == 'button' && inputcCtrls[m].value == 'Finish')
        {
               var funcOnClick = inputcCtrls[m].onclick;
               inputcCtrls[m].onclick = function () {  window.close(); window.location = "http://www.google.com"; };
        }
   }
}

redirect();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with windows in Javascript for a while, but I think there's a window.parent you can access? Possibly set that URL first then close this window?

HTH

Comment: This works but it broke the addition to Survey List. inputcCtrls[m].onclick = function () { window.parent.location = "surveys/Pages/SurveyWirelessThankYou.aspx"; window.close();};

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, so it works but it's broken?

Comment: Javascript redirects to parent page. However, adding new item to the survey list does not work anymore.

Comment: I think I am overwritting and intended onclick function for "Finish" button. I may want to add to existing funcion. How do I tell java that let it do it's native job and additional functionality to the "Finish" button.

Comment: That i'm not sure on, you may want to repost in a javascript group

Answer (score 0):

From the code side this should work:

```
self.opener.location = "http://www.google.com";
```

As you have discovered when you start using javascript events in SharePoint things can get a little funky.  This is called event HiJacking.  I found [this solution](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/rbiggs/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=3), but it only applies to the OnLoad event.  You may be able to modify it to fit your needs for OnCLick.

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}
addLoadEvent(myFunction1);
```

Comment: Actually, onclick has to run it's intended function (in this case, submit the survey which creates record in the survey list). How do I let the onclick run it's original function and add additional function?

Comment: How are you adding onClick?  Through jQuery?